# Low Carb Pizza Dough Recipe - How Will This Make Dough?

Tags: dough, pizza, low-carb

I have found a [low-carb pizza dough recipe](http://lowcarbdiets.about.com/od/pizza/r/deepdishpizza.htm) where you add 6oz of Cream Cheese and 6 eggs to make the dough (also includes some garlic, spices, and cheese).  The recipe claims to be deep-dish, but I just can't see this recipe working out, or tasting good.

I would like some feedback on this, because I really don't have much time when I come home to cook, so if I make it and it doesn't turn out right, I won't have much of a backup plan.

Comment: I know this site isn't about nutritional advice, but you should really consider if you want to replace wheat and water (low fat, relatively low calories, no cholesterol) with cheese and eggs (high fat, high calories, high cholesterol).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Don't think of that as dough. This looks like basically making a quiche base to put pizza toppings on.

I don't see any reason to think this recipe won't be stable but it won't be anything like pizza crust. Still it sounds tasty.

Comment: Not a dough. You may want to look at a [pizza made with cauliflower rice](http://www.examiner.com/low-carb-in-national/cauliflower-pizza-crust-worth-its-wow-gold). I have never made it, but there is even a picture showing it holds up and dozens of positive comments. The low carb cauliflower rice is cauliflower pulsed in the food processor, a well imitated idea by J Beard Award winning author Fran McCullough.

Answer (score 1):

I've actually made this twice now.  First time I did not let the cream cheese get to room temperature, so it wasn't the right consistency.  Second time, the "crust" was right, I just didn't cook it long enough.

The recipe says to cook just the "dough" until it starts getting brown, but you really need to cook it longer.  Next time I cook it, when it starts getting brown, I am going to put olive oil on the "crust" and cook it longer.

The edges (the second time I made it) were real good because they got a little crispy, but the inside was still a little loose.  I must say, this recipe makes a very good pizza.  The biggest problem for me was finding low carb pizza sauce.